# Hash password function not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I am having problems login users in using the below code.

It seems like when I execute my if statement with the correct user password the password entered by the user and the password in my database are not matching up. Can someone give me their input on what I am doing wrong?

```
$pwd = hashed password in my database

$pass = password users enter on logi page



 if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) {



 function PwdHash($pwd, $salt = null)
{
  if ($salt === null)     {
    $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
  }
else     {
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
}
return $salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
}
```

Comment: What does `"print $pwd = " . PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9));` output?  My first guess is that the original pass is hashed with a different `$salt` than what you're doing in your `if` statement.

Comment: Why this line if you have passed the SALT? `$salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);`

Comment: As a side comment, you should really stop using MD5 for passwords. Use crypt/blowfish for example. your method likely has some vulnerability somewhere that negates the point of using it (using plain text is only a bit worse, anyone DB hacking is likely prepared to try to hack passwords)

Comment: thanks, I will look into changing it to crypt/blowfish.

Comment: Hashing your random salt does not make it more random.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone give me their input on what I am doing wrong?

Not to offend you, but you're literally doing *everything* wrong. Let's start right at the beginning:

```
$salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
```

This is a very poor way to calculate a salt. Right from the [`rand` man page](http://php.net/rand):

> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes.

Right there alone, your whole mechanism falls apart. Security is only as good as its weakest component. But it doesn't stop there. `uniqid()` creates a unique id, however the main problem with this is that it is based on the current time. Having a unique salt is good, but since it is strictly time-based, it makes it predictable, which is very bad and far outweighs the benefits of having it unique.

Next, you md5 the salt. This adds absolutely nothing in terms of security and it could possibly be debated that it actually reduces security due to md5 collisions.

Now on to how you're hashing your password:

```
$salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
```

Sha1 is very fast, and is therefore a very bad choice for password hashing. Doing `salt . fastHash(password . salt)` is simply security by obscurity and is not security at all.

---

So what **should** you be doing?

First step: STOP rolling your own password hashing mechanism and leave it in the hands of experts who are smarter than you and I.

Second step: Use [password_hash](http://www.php.net/password_hash). If you don't have PHP 5.5 check the comments on that page for a compatibility library compatible with earlier versions. It's as simple as doing:

```
$hash = password_hash("someAmazingPassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Then see [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for verifying the hashes.

Comment: If you don't have PHP 5.5, you can use this library to add the `password_hash` function.  https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat  (Copied from the manual, for the lazy)  I used to use [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), but I'd suggest `password_hash()` now.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, I will be switching to a more secure method.

Answer (score 0):

You should put SALT_LENGTH to your checking function as you do in your generator function. .
Manually cheking are they different or the same?

Comment: here is what i get for $pwd dfbc8f7410676142d66c6b2742f23e41e92c0bac861393f37                               and here is for $pass  dfbc8f741ee86303d19d21412c84d41dcee65160250b9e191